# Retrieve an array with array index in mongodb when using filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Want to retrieve array elements with its array index as the array is filtered using mongodb aggregation.

> query an array along with its index

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) for finding element at index  from array

```
{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <idx> ] }
```

You can use [indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) for finding index of arry using element

```
{ $indexOfArray: [ <array>, <element> ] }
```

But you must have basic knowledge of [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) too.

Comment: This is some what complex, don't predefined iterator index as javascript map.

Comment: can you please provide sample data as input and output. Thanks.

Comment: Want filter like the one in the link, https://mongoplayground.net/p/I5MXNnY-pTY, to filter only active, inorder to update back I need the array index.

Comment: Use lodash library for index and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Used zip and map to get the index mapping, as in the [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TI8vjJrZ8d2)